# Calculating with TimeSpan and DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

Depending on the current time I need to calculate if a shop is actual open or not. Up to now the opening times are persisted as `TimeSpan`:

```
public TimeSpan OpeningTime { get; set; }
public TimeSpan ClosingTime { get; set; }
```

How can I calculate if the shop has open right now? I tried some thinks but the solutions looked quite cumbersome. One reason is the need to convert between `TimeSpan` and `DateTime`. Is `TimeSpan` the proper format for the opening times? Would a separate class for the time make more sense?

*Note: week days are handled separately*

Comment: Timespans are time-elapsed/interval between 2 datetimes ... not sure how you can use that to represent opening time or closing time.

Comment: Possibly you could have the TimeSpans represent the time from midnight. So `OpeningTime` might be represented by `new TimeSpan(8, 30, 0)` for `8:30 am`, and `ClosingTime` might be `new TimeSpan(22, 0, 0)` for `10:00 pm`. EDIT: So for any given day of the week, you can check if it's open via `if (myDateAtMidnight + OpeningTime < DateTime.Now && myDateAtMidnight + ClosingTime > DateTime.Now)` (but you know, nicer with a nicely named utility method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's open if:

```
OpeningTime <= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= ClosingTime
```

Comment: Exactly. Assuming (which I think is reasonable) that `OpeningTime` is something like `TimeSpan.FromHours(8.0)` to represent 8:00 AM. I think the key here is that OP is not familiar with the `TimeOfDay` property.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a `TimeSpan` is a measure of the *difference between two times*, not an *actual time*.

Assuming you're using the `TimeSpan` to indicate the opening and closing times *relative to midnight* try

```
TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;   
bool isOpen = currentTime > OpeningTime && currentTime < ClosingTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var timeOfDay = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
if (timeOfDay >= OpeningTime && timeOfDay < ClosingTime)
{
    // open now!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` and compare to your 2 TimeSpans

```
    OpeningTime = new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0); // 9:30AM
    ClosingTime = new TimeSpan(17, 30, 0); // 5:30AM

    bool isOpen = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= OpeningTime && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= ClosingTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan OpeningTime = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);
TimeSpan ClosingTime = new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0);

TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now.Date;

if (now > OpeningTime && now < ClosingTime)
{ 
    //...
}
```